# Cluster Autoscaler for AWS EKS cluster in a Private VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

I have an EKS (Kubernetes) Cluster hosted in AWS. Due to some customer data privacy policies this K8s cluster is running in a VPC that is completely cut off from the internet (no internet gateway). The issue I'm having is that the cluster-autoscaler (installed via helm, https://kubernetes.github.io/autoscaler, version 9.25.0) is trying to get pricing data from https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/us-east-1/index.json but the request times out as there is no internet gateway and then the pod errors with the following message
`Failed to generate AWS EC2 Instance Types: unable to load EC2 Instance Type list`

Does anyone have any suggestions, I looked into creating a VPC link but it doesn't look like the pricing API is suppported.